# IntelliJ and JSP HotSwap

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, hotswap

I having been working on this for a couple of days now but still no luck.

I’m using IntelliJ and Wildfly 8 (JBoss) and trying to enable the hotswapping (which is working perfectly in Eclipse).
Although it works fine for the java classes, JSP files are not hotswapped. Here is the details of my environment:

The exploded folder structure looks like this (can’t be changed):

- webapp.war

  - JS
  - IMG
  - CSS
  - WEB-INF

    - classes
    - lib
    - jsps

**The Project Structure:**
[image]

**The Run/Debug Configuration:**
[image]

[image]